# How use asp.net mvc partial view in layout within @RenderPage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have Partial view **LeftBanner.cshtml** that should display some data from DB (images)

**LeftBanner.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.ViewModels.Banner>

    <table class="table">


   <tr>
        <th>Test Banner!</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var banner in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(b => banner.ImageDesc);
                <img src="@Url.Content(banner.ImagePath)" alt="Image" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

**SharedController**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication1.ViewModels;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class SharedController : Controller
    {   
        public ActionResult LeftBanner()
        {
            List<Banner> b = new List<Banner>() {
                new Banner() {ImageDesc = "Left Banner Description", ImagePath = "~/Images/money.jpg" },
                new Banner() {ImageDesc = "Left Banner Description2", ImagePath = "~/Images/money.jpg" }
            };
             return View(b);
           // return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/LeftBanner.cshtml") 
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**The Error**

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'WebApplication1.ViewModels.EmployeeListViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WebApplication1.ViewModels.Banner]'.
```

In Asp.net Web-forms ascx UserControls can be independent and really reusable.

Please help my to understand, why i can't encapsulate my partial view?
It is not real reuse,
If I have to pass to partial view  model every time I use it.
Can it be independent and go to a database without passing it a model?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Add this on top of your Layout page @model WebApplication1.ViewModels

Comment: Hello,
I add @model WebApplication1.ViewModels.Banner to Layout page. Now i get onother error:  The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'WebApplication1.ViewModels.EmployeeListViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'WebApplication1.ViewModels.Banner'.

Comment: Check my bellow answer and let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your LeftBanner() Action method **return** like this,

```
return PartialView("LeftBanner",b);
```

Then in your _Layout.cshtml page, call the action **LeftBanner** like bellow,

```
@Html.Action("LeftBanner", "Shared")
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks a lot!
It's work for @Html.Action("LeftBanner", "Shared") 
How can i use  partial view  with  @RenderPage?
it's possible?

Comment: I'm glad that it helped you. Please mark as answer :)